# changing styles in a loop (JQ)

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering about this strange reaction of jq. When i change styles for one element with my function - all is ok

```
$.fn.setStyle = function(){
 $(this).css('marginLeft','100px');
}

 $(someVar).setStyle();
```

But when i'm using loop to change styles for a multiple elements like

```
$(myHTMLcollection).each(function(index,el){
                  $(el).setStyle();
               });
```

nothing happens, but if i for example `console.log( $(this) )` at the end of my function i see that those elements got new styles in a console, but on page everything still without chages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your code does what it should. Check if something else is overwriting the style.

```js
$.fn.setStyle = function(){
 $(this).css('color','#f00');
}
$('.test').each(function(index, el) {
  $(el).setStyle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='test'>test 1</p>
<p class='test'>test 2</p>
<p class='test'>test 3</p>
<p class='test'>test 4</p>
```

Comment: then maybe other code goes wrong... in any case thank you